# Using ManagedIdentityCredential to get token for user-assigned managed identity

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-managed-identity

I have an Azure App Service with a user-assigned managed identity (the system-assigned managed identity is disabled). When I use ManagedIdentityCredential in my ASP.NET Core web app to get an access token, I get an exception, and dependency telemetry indicates the request to the managed identity endpoint returns 400 Bad Request.

Here's how I call the credential object:

```
var clientID = "<user-assigned-identity-client-id>";
var resourceUrl = "https://<resource-to-be-accessed>";

var credential = new ManagedIdentityCredential(clientID);
var context = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { resourceUrl });
return (await credential.GetTokenAsync(context)).Token;
```

This code closely follows the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#managed-identity-support) in the documentation.

Telemetry shows that when this code executes, the request made to the token endpoint is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:41776/msi/token/?api-version=2019-08-01&resource=REDACTED
```

Based on the [REST endpoint reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal%2Chttp#rest-endpoint-reference), this request should include a `client_id` query parameter, but for some reason it does not.

What's baffling is that if I simulate the production environment locally by setting the same environment variables that are present in production, I can actually step through to the exact point in the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/2cf74f3ca6f4b41783459812ae326252ae19b174/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/src/ManagedIdentitySource.cs#L33) where it's about to send the token request, and see that the `client_id` parameter is present in the request Uri as expected:

```
http://127.0.0.1:41776/msi/token/?api-version=2019-08-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2F<resource>&client_id=<client-id>
```

I can also go to the Console blade for my App Service in the Azure Portal and send the exact same request I observed when running locally, and see that the token endpoint happily returns a valid token:

```
curl -H "X-IDENTITY-HEADER: <header-secret>" -i -s -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:41776/msi/token/?api-version=2019-08-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2F<resource>&client_id=<client-id>"
```

So why is the ManagedIdentityCredential class NOT sending the client ID when it runs in production? Seems clear that if it did, this would just work.

**UPDATE**: Turns out this code *does* work as expected, but there was another place in my code that I didn't know about that was *not* passing the client ID yet, so I was still seeing some "not working" telemetry, which I mistakenly attributed to the code I was modifying.

Leaving this here, though, in case someone wants a good example of how this actually works, and some ways to verify it.